# sshdump' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I am using wireshark version 4.0.7 with "Sshdump, Ciscodump, Wifidump" tool installed. However when i run the sshdump command it gives the error "'sshdump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

For running the command wireskark path is also added in the Environment variables.

does the sshdump gets installed on a different path than usual wireshark path "C:\Program Files\Wireshark"?

Comment: sshdump is present on path "C:\Program Files\Wireshark\extcap". Hence this need to be added in environment variables  to make sshdump work.